# drupal 6 - best jquery version that works?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, drupal-6, upgrade

im starting a project in drupal 6 and i want to know what is the highest version i can use of jquery in the project? i did some upgrades with the jquery_update module but its seems to make troubles , and alot of more troubules with jquery_ui

have anyone managed to update the jquery version with druapl? if so, how and what the highest version its worked without any problems..?

Comment: you shouldn't have any trouble using jquery_update and jquery_ui modules with a vanilla drupal instance if your own code is written correctly. Do you have any specific examples of something breaking?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete step-by-step, tested and user confirmed guide to get jquery-ui version 1.7.3 working. From start to finish.

http://blog.houen.net/drupal-jquery-ui-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Common gotcha with the jquery ui module is failing to add the symbolic link within the module directory to the jquery ui library itself. If you download the full jquery ui bundle to sites/all/libraries, you need to do this:

```
cd /path/to/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui
ln -s ../../libraries/jquery_ui/development-bundle jquery.ui
```

I suspect this is your problem!